# contrast normalization of image python

Tags: python, image-processing

i want to ask how to get the image result (Icon) with python code as indicated in

[image]

where ishade is a preprocessed image and std(Ishade) is the standard deviation of this image

```
result = ndimage.median_filter(blur, size=68)
std=cv2.meanStdDev(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow the article in the reference you posted and the reference in that post to the original. But I do not get exactly what they do. Nevertheless, here is my interpretation (apart from the initial CLAHE). You can adjust the mean and median filter sizes as desired.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Gaussian blurred gray image
mean = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=5, sigmaY=5)

# apply median filter to mean image
median = cv2.medianBlur(mean, 25)

# divide mean by median
division = cv2.divide(mean.astype(np.float64)/255, median.astype(np.float64)/255)

# get global standard deviation of division
std = np.std(division)
print(std)

# divide the division by the std and normalize to range 0 to 255 as unint8
result = np.divide(division, std)
result = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(result, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
    
# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_std_division2.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("mean", mean)
cv2.imshow("median", median)
cv2.imshow("division", division)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much , this is exactly what i want to do , i need this process to detecte some lesions in the retinal images .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want. There are different types of normalization formulae.

The most common would be to subtract the mean from the image and then divide by the standard deviation. `(I-mean(I))/std(I)`

But if you want to do your formulae, `I/std(I)`, then it can be done as follows:

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY).astype(np.float64)/255

# get local mean from blurred gray image and square it
sigma=15
mean = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=sigma, sigmaY=sigma)
mean_sq = cv2.multiply(mean,mean)

# get mean of gray image squared
gray2 = cv2.multiply(gray,gray)
mean2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray2, (0,0), sigmaX=sigma, sigmaY=sigma)

# get variance image from the two means
var = cv2.subtract(mean2, mean_sq)

# get the standard deviation image from the variance image
std = np.sqrt(var)
print(std.dtype, np.amax(std), np.amin(std))

# divide image by std and scale using skimage
divide = (255*cv2.divide(gray, std, scale=1)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
divide = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(divide, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)
print(divide.dtype, np.amax(divide), np.amin(divide))

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_std_division.jpg", divide)

# display it
cv2.imshow("std", std)
cv2.imshow("divide", divide)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result (depending upon the sigma value):

[image]

An alternate formula for which I have posted a number of examples (called division normalization), would be to divide the image by its local mean image. `I/mean(I))`

Comment: thank you for your answer , what i want i to exactly is the shade correction like mentionned is this article :  https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=9056469